# Show summed columns in chart? day/month

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to learn how to show data in charts, and so far I've managed to show data, but I'm having issues with my sql queries, I need it to show me the data in a certain way.

This is my code> I've got 1 combobox from where I select the store name, and 2 datetimepickers.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Provider As String
    Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    Dim dataFile As String
    dataFile = "Original.accdb"


    Dim SqlQry1 As String = "SELECT [Delivered], [Datess] FROM [Table1] WHERE [Store] = @1 AND [Datess] BETWEEN @2 AND @3 ORDER BY [Datess] ASC"


    Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(Provider & dataFile)
        myconnection.Open()

        Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(SqlQry1, myconnection)
        cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@1", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Char, .Value = combobox1.SelectedItem})
        cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@2", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Date, .Value = fromdatess.Value.Date})
        cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@3", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Date, .Value = todatess.Value.Date})


        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read

            Dim asd As String
            asd = dr("Delivered")

            Dim datess As Date
            datess = dr("Datess")

            Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
            Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY(datess.ToShortDateString, asd)


        End While

    End Using


End Sub
```

I want to be able to sum the "Delivered" 
Right now my table is like this>

```
ID    |   Store    |  Delivered |  Datess
 1        Ace1         200         3/1/2018
 2        Ace1         150         3/1/2018
 3        Bis1          50         3/2/2018
 4        Ace1          50         3/2/2018
```

What im trying to do is display it like this>

```
Ace1 350  3/1/2018
Bis1  50  3/2/2018
Ace1  50  3/2/2018
```

As you can see Ace1 is summed. Now I've tried summing it, but it would display the summed result across all days, because I have "BETWEEN Datess and Datess" so its summing between those dates. How can I sum only the day, yet display the data from lets say 1/3/2018 to 1/30/2018 for the whole month. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`

If you want to read from `SUM([Delivered])` give the filed a alias name.

```
SELECT [Store],SUM([Delivered]) AS Delivered, [Datess] 
FROM [Table1] 
WHERE [Store] = @1 AND [Datess] BETWEEN @2 AND @3 
GROUP BY [Store],[Datess] 
ORDER BY [Datess] ASC
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this before, but its throwing me an error System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Delivered' It's pointing down at the dr("Delivered")

Comment: How about give `SUM([Delivered])` a  alisa name?

Comment: I don't know what that means ;S its enough to tell me what to do, I'll do it thanks for the quick replies

Comment: You can try my edit answer :)   alias name.can let `dr("Delivered")` get the data. The key point is `SUM([Delivered]) AS Delivered`

Comment: You saved me so much time. Thank you very much.  Been trying to fix it on my own yesterday for the whole day with no success :S Today I got to see how this group by works, thanks.

Comment: Glad to help you :)